# Laravel - Possibility of having File Upload in Model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, model

I am using Model for All DB Operations

i.e.,

**In the Controller**

```
public function VehicleProcess()
{
$VehicleData = Input::all();
$validation = Validator::make($VehicleData, VehicleModel::$rules);  // using model for validation
if ($validation->passes())
   {
     VehicleModel::create($VehicleData);   //using model for creating table
     return Redirect::to('vehicle')->withErrors('Vehicle Details Saved Succesfully');
   }
```

Now I am using File Upload

So, Getting the file

```
$file = Input::file('photo');
```

And Storing it in my Own Destination Path

```
Input::file('photo')->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
```

I am Doing all this in Controller,

**Is it possible to do these things in Model like sending $file to Model, If so How can I do that?**

Answer (score 1):

You can handle requests however you want. Laravel does not force you to code your controllers in specific ways.

Separation of concerns, however, is a great practice. [In his book](https://leanpub.com/laravel), Taylor sheds some light on this issue, using interfaces and dependency injection. Basically your controllers normally depend on some interfaces. For DB operations, let's say, your VehicleController would use VehicleRepository. And for file system manipulation, your VehicleController would use another interface (maybe called ImageManager). All these interfaces and their implementations you shall code by yourself.

Code sample in controller:

```
class VehicleController extends BaseController {


protected $vehicle;

protected $imageManager;


function __construct(VehicleRepositoryInterface $vehicle, ImageManager $imageManager)
{
    $this->vehicle = $vehicle;
    $this->imageManager = $imageManager;
}
```

Next, you have to code a ServiceProvider class to bind an implementation to your interface so that Laravel could automatically load and inject that implementation into your controller at runtime.

```
class RepositoryServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider{

/**
 * Register the service provider.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind(
        'VehicleRepositoryInterface',
        'EloquentVehicleRepository'
    );
}
```

And this [blog article](http://culttt.com/2013/07/08/creating-flexible-controllers-in-laravel-4-using-repositories/) also discusses the topic very well.

In sum, in your case file manipulation is very likely to be needed in many controllers, so I think it is better to move such logic into specific interfaces and classes than to code it in models.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, will the function **__construct** gets the `$file` or  `Input::file('InsurancePhoto');` automatically ?

Comment: I would suggest you make a new function in your file handling specific class that is responsible for saving files. The constructor is pretty much a place where you let Laravel to inject classes into your controller.

Answer (score 0):

you can override create method of model

```
class VehicleModel extends \Eloquent {


public static function create(array $attributes) {

        if(isset($attributes['photo'])){
            //put you file tranfer code
            $attributes['photo'] = "demo.jpg";
        }

        return parent::create($attributes);
    }
}
```